# Intermittent delayed ignition, gas furnace

Tags: furnace, gas

I have a more than 22 year old gas furnace that appears to be having a delayed ignition problem but the loud bang only happens once every few days and the HVAC tech that came over to look at it found nothing wrong, it worked just fine for him (he checked for CO, cracked heat exchanger, incomplete ignition and a blocked chimney).

The unit is a ICP/Tempstar/Heil 867.767052 / NUGI150DK03, has electronic spark ignition and the igniter was replaced two years ago. The ignition sequence appears to operate correctly with clear blue flames

I would prefer to start by replacing individual components rather than the whole furnace (although having examined the name plate date to update this question, I think it needs to go) but no one on the internets seems to have any suggestions for this intermittent condition which seems like it should be curable, or at least understandable.

Can anyone suggest anything? Thanks!

Comment: Based on the info provided, I'd recommend replacing the discombobulator and checking blinker fluid. If you'll [edit] to provide a brand/model, someone might be able to give you more specific info.

Comment: Thanks, I added model number and other details but I was thinking if there is an answer it should be generic? As in, if there is a very intermittent delayed  ignition that can't be replicated it's most likely the discombobulator...? Or: it is hopeless because it's not a replaceable part, something you can't see is rusted, get a new furnace?

Comment: I'm no HVAC expert, so I can't guide you, but with that additional info, I'm sure _someone_ will stop by soonish to give you some guidance

Comment: You've mentioned delayed ignition and a loud bang. Are you saying that the gas sometimes ignites explosively rather than the usual, more gentle whoosh? Photos of the burner area could be helpful, as could video of one or two ignition events.